# How to have 3 conditions to fulfill in CASE WHEN in SQL

Tags: sql, case-when

I am having difficulty when trying to have 3 conditions to fulfill in CASE WHEN in SQL server. Here is my original script but only return value 0 instead of 1 and 0. My purpose is to check when a customer purchase ITEM_01 with more than or equal to 0.06 AND ITEM_02 with more than or equal to 0.06 THEN return value 1 else 0. Here is my script:

```
CASE WHEN SUM ( CASE WHEN ITEM_01)='DH' AND (ITEM_02)='DH Classic' THEN NVL
(SALE_OUTLETD.PRE_SALES_QTY * SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER,0) + NVL 
(SALE_OUTLETD.SALES_QTY * SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER, 0) -NVL 
(SALE_OUTLETD.FRESH_RTN_QTY *SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER, 0) - NVL 
(SALE_OUTLETD.OLD_RTN_QTY * SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER,0) - NVL 
(SALE_OUTLETD.DAMAGED_RTN_QTY *SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER, 0) - NVL
(SALE_OUTLETD.WITHDRAWAL_RTN_QTY *SKU_UOM_CONV.MULTIPLIER, 0) ELSE 0 END )
>= 0.06 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 3_PACK_AND_ABOVE
```

Please help on this question because I have been stuck for few hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I advice you to check the content of your inner case. Display ITEM_01, ITEM_02 and the case itself to see if you have values >=0.06

Comment: Hi @StevenBENET, yes there are quite a number of records for that so that trigger my problem here on returning only value 0. Thanks

Comment: What about the sum ? Because in the end, that is the sum which should be > 0.06

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded an image from my outcome, this could help for better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: your new sql is wrong. problem with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding your example impossible to read but the basic form of `CASE` is:

```
select case WHEN first_boolean THEN first_value
            WHEN second_boolean THEN second_value
            WHEN third_boolean THEN third_value
            ...
            ELSE default_value
```

Always try to build things off that model.  Nested CASE statements like what you are doing are never fun and tend to be fairly error prone.

Comment: Hi @Chris Travers, thank you for the advise. May I know how to check when both nett sales for ITEM_01 and ITEM_02 have the sales of >= 0.06? I have edit the script to make it easier to read, sorry for any inconvenience caused. Thanks.